# corroded battery on old calculator

Tags: batteries, corrosion

I am attempting to revive an old HP-41CV calculator.  Everything works, but one of the leads on the battery pack is corroded.  Is there a quick fix, or will I have to figure out how to replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is enough of it left, you can simply file it down until you have exposed a clean surface of metal. Things that may also be of use are aluminum foil and conductive silver paint, a soldering iron and a small piece of replacement metal. I have fixed plenty of contacts (just last night in fact revived an old wireless keyboard) in this manner.

EDIT - just occurred to me you may mean the battery (pack) itself, in which case you may well need to replace it if it is leaking (is corrosion visible on case of battery?) If in any doubt replace the battery pack with a new one, as it may end up leaking badly and damaging things. If battery pack is of a special type no longer available, post a pic/specs (size, nominal voltage and mAh) and we can think about a DIY replacement using currently available cells.

Answer (score 1):

First, clean it as thoroughly as you can. You don't want corrosion continuing.

Then, a method that I've seen suggested but haven't tried personally is to wrap some aluminum foil around whatever is available from the old terminal. It's said to work well where it works. i there will be places where foil doesn't belong or you cant get mechanical attachment.

Try to avoid high resistance at join. Measuring voltages when operating with new terminal will tell you how much of battery is getting to the equipment.